# What is the issue after creating replication in mongod server?

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb I created replications After created replications
  then again started the mongod Sever without replication it gives warnings like
  below. Why these warnings came in both mongod server and also mongo client?

mongod server:

```
2015-06-24T11:48:21.295+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: mongod start
ed without --replSet yet 1 documents are present in local.system.replset
2015-06-24T11:48:21.296+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          Restart with
--replSet unless you are doing maintenance and  no other clients are connected.

2015-06-24T11:48:21.296+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          The TTL coll
ection monitor will not start because of this.
2015-06-24T11:48:21.296+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **
2015-06-24T11:48:21.297+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]  For more info see http:
//dochub.mongodb.org/core/ttlcollections
2015-06-24T11:48:21.298+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2015-06-24T11:48:21.299+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections
on port 27017
2015-06-24T11:48:39.269+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from
127.0.0.1:2979 #1 (1 connection now open)
```

mongo client:

```
2015-06-24T11:48:39.233+0530 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not
installed, will zero-out data files
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
2015-06-24T11:48:21.295+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2015-06-24T11:48:21.295+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: mongod start
ed without --replSet yet 1 documents are present in local.system.replset
2015-06-24T11:48:21.296+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          Restart with
--replSet unless you are doing maintenance and  no other clients are connected.

2015-06-24T11:48:21.296+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          The TTL coll
ection monitor will not start because of this.
2015-06-24T11:48:21.298+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
```